# relational database queries are not working mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a relational database in MySql but i am getting an error and I really cant figure out what’s wrong with my query.

Below is the error is get :

```
Error Code : 1072
Key column 'user_id' doesn't exist in table
(0 ms taken)
```

Here is my query :

```
CREATE TABLE tish_user(
user_id int(11) NOT NULL Auto_increment,
username varchar(30) NOT NULL,
Password varchar(41) NOT NULL,
Previllage VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
date_created datetime,
primary key (user_id )
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE tish_images(
image_id int(11) not null auto_increment,
image_name varchar(100) not null,
image_profile numeric(1) default 0,
FOREIGN KEY(user_id)REFERENCES tish_user(user_id)on update cascade,
primary key (image_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE tish_clientinfor(
client_id int(11) not null auto_increment,
title  varchar(11) not null,
firstname varchar(30) not null,
lastname  varchar(30) not null,
client_code  varchar(30) not null,
date_registered  timestamp Default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
FOREIGN KEY(user_id)REFERENCES tish_user(user_id)on update cascade,
primary key (client_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: @DMK you did a relevant edit thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have a `user_id` column in `tish_clientinfor` as referenced by `FOREIGN KEY(user_id)...`. Did you perhaps mean to add one?

```
CREATE TABLE tish_clientinfor(
client_id int(11) not null auto_increment,
title  varchar(11) not null,
firstname varchar(30) not null,
lastname  varchar(30) not null,
client_code  varchar(30) not null,
date_registered  timestamp Default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
user_id int(11) not null, --this was the missing column
FOREIGN KEY(user_id)REFERENCES tish_user(user_id)on update cascade,
primary key (client_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

The same is true for table `tish_images`.

Comment: Thanks but should i make it auto increment again in other tables?

Comment: @humphrey Why would you do that? You want to be able to specify which user for each record, right?